# How to increment value in for loop which is declared as string in code, but has numeric val?

Tags: excel, vba

This code returning error in the `For` loop because of a type mismatch:

```
  Dim sp, q, spb, spt, cp, cpb, cpt, g, n, i As String
  n = Range("G3").Value
  cp = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value
  q = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
  cpt = cp * q
  cpb = cp * n
  i = 0.05
  For i = 0.05 To 10
    sp = cp + i
    spt = (sp * q)
    spb = spt * n
    g = spt - cpt - spb - cpb
    If g > 0 Then
      Range("I10").Value = g
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Declare/Dim your variables to be of the correct type:

```
Dim i As Double
```

For the other variables, a numerical type would be appropriate too. If Excel has problems pulling them from Cells of String type, use a conversion (CDbl, CLng, ...), before you do the computations.

Comment: How to convert excel clmn values to int and add again them with other clmn variables and store back in excel

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, dim your variable(s) correctly.  For instance in your code sp, q, spb, spt, cp, cpb, cpt, g, n are all set to the "variant" type, which may or may not be what you're after.  My guess is that you're wanting to set them all as strings, which would mean you'd have to do something like:

Dim sp as String, q as String, spb as String (etc, etc, etc). Of course, doing that will cause a lot of your code down the line to bomb (cpt = cp * q as an example).

Also, the default increment of a loop is 1.  Is that what you're expecting in your for loop?  In your example above, your for loop never gets to 10 (stops at 9.05).

I'm not sure if this helps you at all, but hopefully it will clear up any confusion down the road.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There a validation call you can make to the cell first:

```
If IsNumeric(Range("I10").Value) then
    '// Do some numeric stuff 
else    
'// Do some non-numeric stuff

endif
```

There is a Val() function to try and interpret string content as numbers:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/HV080557263.aspx